# Why does the rich text editor sometimes show HTML code instead of rich text?

Tags: 2007, rich-text

I have a list in a SharePoint 2007 site with some rich text fields (type - 'Multiple lines of text'). Most users use the rich text editor and Internet Explorer to edit these fields.

When editing list items, most fields show rich text as expected. But a few list items instead show HTML code inside the rich text editor, for example:

```
 <DIV><A href="http://foo/baz.pdf">Baz</A></DIV>
```

When viewing the list items, links and text appear as expected.

Why does the rich text editor sometimes show HTML code instead of rich text? What caused the problem? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

this can be fixed using the compatability view.

[image]

can you see the broken document after the url, click that and it will fix the rich text exitor.

a close up:

[image]

issue mainly occures in new browsers for legacy versions of sharepoint e.g. ie 11 for sharepoint 2007

Comment: thanks. I tried enabling compatibility view by selecting Tools | Compatibility View Settings, and refreshed the page. This didn't solve the problem. Also, if it's working fine for other list items, I don't really understand why compatibility view would be the solution.